# Updating subviews in cells on a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I'm developing an application in iPad 6.0 using Storyboards.

Let me first explain my goal. I'm trying to achieve a Master-Detail (SplitViewController-like) View Controller using 2 UITableViewControllers.

The first UITableView("Master"), let's call this **HeaderTableView**, as the name implies, lists down the Headers for the...

...Second UITableView("Detail"), let's call this the **EncodingTableView**, which contains a programmatically changing CustomTableViewCell (subviews contained within each cell may be a UITextField, UIButton or UISwitch).

See **EncodingTableView.m**

```
- (void)updateEncodingFields:(NSArray *)uiViewList
{
    // Add logic for determining the kind of UIView to display in self.tableView

    // Finally, notify that a change in data has been made (not working)
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            NSString *encodingFieldsTableId = @"encodingFieldsTableId";

            CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:encodingFieldsTableId];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:encodingFieldsTableId];
            }
            // Change text in textView property of CustomTableViewCell
            cell.encodingFieldTitle.text = uiViewList.title;
            // added methods for determining what are to be added to [cell.contentView addSubView:]
            // data used here is from the array in updateEncodingFields:

        }
```

My **HeaderTableView.m**, contains the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to update the **EncodingTableView**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            if (![selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
                selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
                [self updateDataFieldTableViewForIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
        }

    - (void)updateDataFieldTableViewForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self.encodingTableView updateEncodingFields:self.uiViewList];
    }
```

**Question**
 - Data is all ok but why doesn't **EncodingTableView** "redraw"ing the fields? My
   suspicion is that reusing cells has something to do with this but I just can't figure out why.

Screenshots on the result:
**Initial Selection in HeaderTableView**
[image: Initial Selection]

**Second Selection in HeaderTableView**
[image: Second Selection]

What I've tried :

- I kept seeing suggestions such as [UITableView setNeedsDisplay],
  [UITableView reloadData] and [UITableView setNeedsLayout] but none of
  them worked.
- Removing the reuse of tableViewCells works fine but this causes parts of my
  CustomTableView.encodingFieldTitle to disappear. Not to mention that this might cause performance issues if I were to drop reusing cells.

**Restrictions**:
I know that a good idea is to use a SplitViewController but this is just a subpart of my app (hence not the RootViewController).

Finally, thanks for reading such a long post. ;)

Comment: Please show your entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method without commenting out anything. That's the only relevant method for debugging all "cell does not redraw" issues.

Comment: do not use dequeuereuse your cell, and try then.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight all that's left of the cellForRowAtIndexPath which is relevant is the adding of subviews : [cell.contentView addSubview:fieldView];

Comment: @SaurabhSingh as mentioned in the "What I've tried" part, I did remove the dequeuereuse for my cell but this causes parts of the CustomTableViewCell to disappear. Upon debugging, I found out that the cell's view are <null>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are most likely adding subviews inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

The issue is that if you use cell reuse then are not always starting from a blank slate inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead you can possibly be given a cell back that has already been configured once. This is what you are seeing, a cell that has previously had labels added to it is handed back to you and then you add some more labels over the top.

There are a few way to deal with this:

1. (My preferred option) Create a subview of `UITableViewCell` with these extra sub views available as properties.
2. Ensure the cell setup is only done once
   A great place to do this is when you actually create a cell when one does not already exist e.g. inside the `if (cell)` check

   ```
   if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:encodingFieldsTableId];

     // add subview's here and give them some way to be referenced later
     // one way of doing it is with the tag property (YUK)
     UILabel *subView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithframe:someFrame];
     subView.tag = 1;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:subView];
   }

   UILabel *label = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
   label.text = @"some value";
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried out option 2 but the weird thing is I couldn't access `(id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]` when I wanted to change my label text. Let me try option 1 for a while.

Answer (score 2):

One problem i can see in your code is that the cell identifiers used are different in tableView cellForRowAtIndxPath function.

While dequeueing you are using this identifier - > "encodingFieldsTableId"

&

while creating a cell you are using this identifier - > "dataFieldUiGroupTableId".

Ideally these two identifiers should be same !!!

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. Updated my answer above. Thanks for the quick eye!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding,

```
cell.encodingFieldTitle.text = nil;
```

Before `if(cell == nil)`

So that whenever your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called, the string already present in the cell you are going to reuse will get deleted and the new text in `uiViewList.title` will be displayed.